# How long before on hold questions get closed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, on-hold

Just curious. One question shows up as [closed], even if it was asked just 40 minutes ago. But I thought questions were [on hold] for days before showing up as closed!

[image]

So is this just a glitch, was this question deemed unsalvageable by the system, or is something more sinister going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question *is* on hold, [see the post itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274577/should-i-delete-and-restart-my-wp-site).

You are looking at a search result (the `Q:` labels are only used there to distinguish from `A:` answers). The search engine only uses the *[closed]* label.

That's because the *on hold* status is nothing more than a (timed) alternative title for *closed*, but the way the search engine indexes data it is harder to put the alternative label display logic in the search results listing.

Comment: Wait, yes, I was filtering on the [css] tag. Sorry, hadn't realised that would make such a difference. Indeed, in that case the list of questions does say [closed]. So you're right and now I'll have to wait 3 minutes before I can accept this.

Comment: @MrLister: you were *searching* for the `[css3]` tag with additional constraints. :-) Unless you used a post type constraint, then there are also answers in that result list.

Comment: @MrLister: (if it showed up in a `[css]` search then the tags were changed during the grace period and the index is still to catch up).

Comment: I was searching for **css\***, sorry if you got confused.